# jqm-datebox 'setTheDate' option errs

Tags: jquery-mobile

In the jqm-datebox plugin for jquery-mobile, there is an option 'setTheDate', whose usage is described in the documentation like so:

```js
$('element').datebox('setTheDate', <date>);
```

When I use it, I get an error:

```js
$('#dateboxElement').datebox('setTheDate', new Date() );
```

> TypeError: Object [object Date] has no method 'get'

The plugin seems to expect the date object to have a method get(). I know there's getDay(), getMonth(), etc, but certainly no get().

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work like this:

```
$(element).trigger('datebox', {
    "method":    "set",
    "value":     "2013-09-18", //I think this needs to be in the format datebox uses
    "date":      new Date()
});
```

There's a lot of other events like this in the "Event Payload" section here:
http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/events.html